# Write a Select Statement to Query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query the first letter of a last name in MySQL. I want to skip the first name and query the a certain letter in the last name. Thanks

In SKU_data, which SKU has a buyer whose last name begins with 'M'?
*/

```
select *
from sku_data
where buyer ;
```

Comment: Some example will help here.

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause, search on `WHERE buyer.LastName LIKE 'M%'`. This will return all results that start with M.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of the `substring` method and the `substring_index` method in your sql query.

Your select query should look something like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(last_name,1,1)
```

I'm assuming that your name field has both first and last name in it, instead of separate fields for first and last name.  Use the `substring_index` method to figure out what `last_name` should be:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name,' ',-1)
```

Combining this SQL, we have:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(buyer,' ',-1),1,1) as first_letter
```

Now you can use the first_letter field in a where clause to get your desired result:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(buyer,' ',-1),1,1) as first_letter
from sku_data
where first_letter = 'M' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a field like say "full_name" which has first name and last name in the same column.

> Lets say the full_name in table employee has a value "JEFF MOSTI"

You can simply use the following statement to get what you need

```
select * from employee where full_name regexp ' M';
```

I am assuming you are looking for the last name to start with 'M' and that there is a space (' ') between the first and last name.